# Distribute points to objects by a given function

Tags: python

I have an idea but I'm stuck with implemention for something basic.
I'm trying to make a points division (Limited number of points) to a certain amount of objects. What does that mean-
If we assume I have 100 points divided into 5 objects, let's say we'll list the objects in the list:
[1,2,3,4,5]

The first place in list will have the highest number of points. Then the second highest place followed and so on ..
I want a function that divides the following points in descending order according to a given function (eg linear, exponential, constant, etc.)
I hope I explained well .. I did my best :)
Does anyone know a package in Python or a nice way to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a list of the objects to which you want to give points. Then you can do:

```py
totpoints=100
score=[] #this list holds the score based on position
totscore=0 #this will be the sum of all the scores
for i in range(len(lst)): #lst is the list
    if mode=="linear":
        score[i]=i
    elif mode=="quadratic":
        score[i]=i*i
    elif mode=="exponential":
        score[i]=exp(i)
    else: #constant
        score[i]=1
for i in score:
    totscore+=i
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i].send(round(score[i]*totpoints/totscore)
    #assuming you send the values by some method of the objects
```

This actually gives the most points to the ones with an higher index, so you would first reverse the `score` list to get higher-first.
Obviously the best way to use this is inside a function that you'll then be able to call with different `mode`s, `totpoints` and `lst`s.

GOTCHA: this may give out a larger or smaller number of points than you actually wanted, depending on the rounding of the values. If you need to be precise add a check for the total number of points you send.

I was almost forgetting: if you need the points as a list, you can do

```
points=[round(s*totpoints/totscore) for s in score]
```

Comment: amazing !! Thank you so much !! <3

Comment: To calm also use a list comprehension instead of the last for loop, see last edit in the answer